# Stuck in 'Cut Links' Mode While Working On Nodes

Tags: modeling, node-editor, shortcut

I've somehow entered into some accessibility mode while working on nodes in shading where my cursor / left click is always performing 'cut links'. Holding CTRL allows me to select new objects, but I cannot move them in this mode, nor can I make new links in the traditional fashion.

After an hour of searching I am at a loss. How do I disable this and enter into the normal mode?

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me(don't really know how it happened), but that's how I solved it: click the arrow in top left corner of the geo nodes view and click on "Use box selection..." instead of "Links Cut"

[image]